# Graphs creation using Raphaël

Tags: graph, raphael

I am trying to accomplish this same graph: http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html but the thing is I will be needing multiple graphs on the same page and this won't allow me to do so, could anyone help me out? I've been messing around with the code inside the demo but haven't been able to successfully allow me to show multiple graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html)?